# How to write short code with if else to get page_id?

Tags: wp-query, pages

```
<div class="group-training">

    <?php while ( $page_loop->have_posts() ) : $page_loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="entry">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>                        
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php
        $page_args = array( 'page_id' => 86 );
        $page_loop = new WP_Query ( $page_args );
    ?>
    <div class="lordag">
        <?php while ( $page_loop->have_posts() ) : $page_loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>                        
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        $page_args = array ( 'page_id' => 88 );
        $page_loop = new WP_Query ( $page_args );
    ?>

    <div class="sondag">
        <?php while ( $page_loop->have_posts() ) : $page_loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>                        
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code gets hidden. Please, fix your [Markdown syntax](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Care to explain a bit? what you need? what have you tried? what does the code you posted have to do with the title?

Comment: Thank for your answer, i want use if else to check page id, i begin wordpress and php

Answer (score 0):

I use this maybe helpfull

```
<?php
   $title = get_the_title($post); 
   $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);

   echo $title;
   echo $parent_title;
  ?>


<?php
  global $post; //wordpress post global object
  if($post->post_type == 'page'){
    $content .= '<br /> This item is a page and the ID is: '.$post->ID;
  } elseif($post->post_type == 'post') {
    $content .= '<br /> This item is a post and the ID is: '.$post->ID;
  }
  echo $content;

?>
```